# How can we optimize these lines of code?

Tags: php, arrays, try-catch

I want to know is there any way we can optimize lines of code. I know we can write the other `$row[] = $this->getFields($inputHeaders, $result, $fields['row2']);` in the first try block. But i still want to know is there any other way of reducing these lines of code or any better way of doing it

```
try {
        $row[] = $this->getFields($inputHeaders, $result, $fields['row1']);
    } catch (BAS_Shared_InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $logger->err($e->getMessage());

        return false;
    }

    // Get data for first row.
    try {
        $row[] = $this->getFields($inputHeaders, $result, $fields['row2']);
    } catch (BAS_Shared_InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $logger->err($e->getMessage());

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What do you really try to optimise for? Execution time? Memory consumption?  Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Optimization is not really a suitable SO topic. Code Review is more suited to that, but even there you would need to, as a minimum, include the definition of the `getFields` method, and clarify what you mean by `optimize` - faster to execute? Easier to read? simply less lines/chars?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it was asked about **refactoring**, and not about **optimisation** I give following answer:

```
$rowNames = array('row1', 'row2');

foreach ($rowNames as $rowName) {
    try {
        $row[] = $this->getFields($inputHeaders, $result, $fields[$rowName]);
    } catch (BAS_Shared_InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $logger->err($e->getMessage());

        return false;
    }
}
```